# Selecting newest entries with different types

Tags: sql-server, performance

I'm designing table which will contain properties of some objects which will change over time.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ObjectProperties]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    [ObjectType] SMALLINT NOT NULL, 
    [Width] SMALLINT NOT NULL, 
    [Height] SMALLINT NOT NULL, 
    [Weight] SMALLINT NOT NULL
)
```

Let's say I have this ObjectTypes:
1 = Chair
2 = Table

And Data for this table:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ObjectProperties] ([Id], [ObjectType], [Width], [Height], [Weight]) VALUES (1, 1, 50, 50, 1000)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ObjectProperties] ([Id], [ObjectType], [Width], [Height], [Weight]) VALUES (2, 2, 80, 40, 500)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ObjectProperties] ([Id], [ObjectType], [Width], [Height], [Weight]) VALUES (3, 1, 50, 50, 2000)
```

So, as you can see I had Chair object which Weight was 1000 then I changed weight to 2000. And I'm storing something like modification history of objects properties.
Now I want to select newest data from this table for each object. I know how to select newest data for each object one by one:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [ObjectProperties] WHERE ObjectType = 1 ORDER BY Id DESC
```

But what if I want to select few objects with one query? Like

```
SELECT ... * FROM [ObjectProperties] WHERE ObjectType IN (1, 2) ...
```

And receive rows with ids 2 and 3 (because 3 has newer properties for Chair than 1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a CTE with `ROW_NUMBER` ranking function:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *, 
       RN=ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ObjectType ORDER BY ID DESC)
    FROM [ObjectProperties] op
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
AND ObjectType IN (1, 2)
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0ed9d/2/0)

The `ROW_NUMBER` returns one row for every `ObjectType`-group order by `ID DESC`(so the record with the highest ID) .If you want to filter by certain ID's you just have to apply the appropriate `WHERE` clause, either in the CTE or in the outer `SELECT`.

[**Ranking Functions**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)

Comment: So, this way is faster than simple select in select?

Comment: The ranking functions are very efficient, but - more important - they are more readable and maintainable than sub selects with `GROUP BY`s. Btw, thanks for 100k Reps :)

Answer (score 3):

A simple (admittedly crude) way is as follows:

```
select * from ObjectProperties where id in
   (select max(id) from ObjectProperties group by objecttype)
```

This gives:

```
Id          ObjectType Width  Height Weight
----------- ---------- ------ ------ ------
2           2          80     40     500
3           1          50     50     2000
```